# Collection.update({_id: id}, {$set: {imgName: name, imgBase64: buffer} }); responds with 0 in console

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to upload an image to MongoDB with a `FileReader`,
code in helper is as follows:

```
Template.Producto.events({
  'change #file-upload': function (event, template) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var name = event.target.files[0].name;
    var id = this._id._str;
    if (!file) return;
    // Only process image files.
    if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
      alert('Only image files are allowed');
      return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (file) {
      var result = reader.result;
      Meteor.call('saveFile', name, result, id);
    }
    Session.set('file', name);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); //read the file as base64
    console.log(id);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(file);
  }
});
```

and my method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'saveFile': function (name, buffer, id, data) {

    console.log(id);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(buffer);
    Productos.update({_id: id}, {
      $set: {
        imgName: name, imgBase64: buffer
      }
    })
  }
});
```

The thing is, I also cannot update my document from the front-end console doing this.

If I update from console, the console returns a 0 number 
also my document has a multidimensional array on the id (the product object comes from a mongoimport from a json document, so the id can be reachable this way).

If I try to access the `id` with `_str`, the console returns an error:

```
errorClass 
{
  error: 403,
  reason: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID.",
  details: undefined,
  message: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]",
  errorType: "Meteor.Error"
}
```

my `Products.allow` is as follow

```
Productos = new Mongo.Collection('productos');

Productos.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  update: function(userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function(userId, doc) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to acces the id with _str? Does the data get stored in the MongoDB database?

Comment: Im accesing the id in line 5 of Template.Producto.events like this 
var id = this._id._str; also i know im getting the id since i send it to the console bot on server and client and is being reflected there, another thing to point, i modified the code to insert instead of update and that works correctly,
code: Productos.insert({imgName: name, imgBase64: buffer});
 what is not working is updating with this
Productos.update({_id: id}, {$set: {imgName: name, imgBase64: buffer} })

Comment: Normally, you should not supply the _id yourself. Why would you do that? If you need to supply a unique identifier from the client, use another custom field. In most cases, though, this is not necessary. Didn't you place `id` in the `_str` property? Why don't you query by it?

Comment: queried by alias and now is working!!!!

Comment: Congrats! You should probably either delete the question or post your solution and explain what went wrong.

Comment: the problem was a bad query and was solved by querying correctly by alias, i dont know how to query by a multidimensional array which is what is my id field

Comment: Yes, that might have been the `this._id._str` line or something. Hard to tell without knowing the structure of your template. There are powerful debugging tools. Use them :)